# Hyperopt parameter space: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Apply'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

This ran perfectly before I updated several packages, including scikit-learn. Now, the code below gives me a TypeError.

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, Trials

def para_space():

    space_paras = {'model_type': hp.choice('model_type', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']),
                    'output_units': hp.uniform('output_units', 1, 10)}
    return space_paras

if __name__=='__main__':

    params = para_space()

    if params['model_type'] == 'f1':
            include_hours = True
            include_features = False
    else:   
            include_hours = True
            include_features = True

    out = int(params['output_units'])
```

I am using python 2.7.12, `hyperopt` version 0.1, and `sklearn` version 0.18.1. Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testJan25.py", line 26, in <module>
    out = int(params['output_units'])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Apply'
```

Any idea how I can cast the result from `hp.uniform` as an integer?

EDIT:

Suppose I use `hp.randint` instead:

```
def para_space():

        space_paras = {'model_type': hp.choice('model_type', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']),
                        'output_units': hp.randint('output_units', 10)}
        return space_paras
```

and later:

```
    print params['output_units']
```

Then this is the output:

```
0 hyperopt_param
1   Literal{output_units}
2   randint
3     Literal{10}
```

but the whole point of hyperopt is to give you random values for hyperparameter optimization. Surely there's a way to extract a value from this?

Comment: Huh, never used the library but that error doesn't match what I'd expect from the docs as far as I can see. Take a step back, what do you get from `print(type(hp.uniform('output_units', 1, 10)))` without any other code?

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the tip. I get: `<class 'hyperopt.pyll.base.Apply'>`. I'm using 2.7.12, my bad.

Comment: I should have looked harder. Why do you think you should be able to cast a distribution to `int`? It looks as though it returns an object that is to be used in a solver internal to that library. If you wanted to view a similar range, use `np.linspace`.

Comment: Ooh, that generates a lot more questions: why would this code have ever run, if a distribution is returned instead of a single value? Why is this not happening with the True/False values? How can I generate an actual random integer (I tried with `hp.randint`, and got the same error)?

Comment: Well, the code doesn't run, it throws an exception. It looks like `uniform` is to define a search space for optimising a function between a lower and upper bound (again, I've never used this library). It would be pointless to try optimising if the search space was a single integer

Comment: Yes, but it ran before I upgraded scikit-learn. I agree, a search space should be defined, but you also need to generate samples to try for hyperparameter optimization. I'm following the general setup here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1591 (post by jacobzweig). The values here can be fed directly in to models - my problem is that the value needs to be an integer.

Comment: I'm at my limit here sorry because I'm not familiar with the library. It's possible that they saw an optimisation to be made by creating a specific object that yields results on demand rather than giving a pre-determined list of distinct values in that range. One last suggestion is `print(dir(hp.uniform('output_units', 1, 10)))` and look for an attribute that might give a value (e.g. `value`) in that list. Assuming `value`, or something similar, exists, you'd retrieve it with `hp.uniform('output_units', 1, 10).value`.

Answer (score 1):

The `hyperopt` package allows you to define a parameter space. To sample values of that parameter space to use in a model, you need a Trials() object.

```
def model_1(params):
        #model definition here....
    return 0

params = para_space()
#model_1(params) #THIS IS A PROBLEM! YOU CAN'T CALL THIS. YOU NEED A TRIALS() OBJECT.

trials = Trials()
best = fmin(model_1, params, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=1, trials=trials)
```